# Not generating random number

Tags: javascript, html, random

I am making a website that will generate a random number using JS. But it shows `undefined` for some reason. I DON'T want that to come. Here is my code.

```js
var showRandomNumberDiv = document.getElementById("show-random-number");
var number1 = document.getElementById("number-1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number-2");
var generate = document.getElementById("generate");

var newPara = document.createElement("p");
generate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  numbers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i > number1 && i < number2; i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  newPara.innerHTML = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
  showRandomNumberDiv.appendChild(newPara);
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello, and welcome to Random generator!</h1>
<h2>Not only numbers, but letters too!</h2>
<p>If you want to enter a <span style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;">positive</span> number, see below.</p>

<!-- Generate a random number -->

<input type="text" placeholder="number 1" id="number-1">
<input type="text" placeholder="number 2" id="number-2">
<input type="button" value="Generate" id="generate">
<div id="show-random-number">

</div>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you debug the code? just add `debugger` to a line before `numbers = []` and see each step and what are you missing...

Comment: *"i > number1 && i < number2"* those are input elements so you need to get the value it should be `i > number1.value && i < number2.value`

Comment: `newPara.innerHTML = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];`.  Okay, so, `Math.random()` generates a value between 0 and 1 (here's a demo, it took me 3 seconds to put together: [demo](https://jsbin.com/masejiholu/edit?html,js,console,output)).  So, you're selecting say, the index of 0.75*2, so, your index key is 1.5?  But pushing adds keys like 1=>value, 2=> value? I don't see how this is supposed to work at all?

Comment: Isn't the input supposed to have some value such as value="1" then access it via `var number1 = document.getElementById("number-1").value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did made a few mistakes in your code. Here's fixed version:

```js
var showRandomNumberDiv = document.getElementById("show-random-number");
var number1 = document.getElementById("number-1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number-2");
var generate = document.getElementById("generate");

var newPara = document.createElement("p");
showRandomNumberDiv.appendChild(newPara);

generate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var numbers = [];
  for (var i = parseInt(number1.value); i < parseInt(number2.value); i++) {
    numbers.push(i);
  }
  newPara.innerHTML = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello, and welcome to Random generator!</h1>
<h2>Not only numbers, but letters too!</h2>
<p>If you want to enter a <span style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;">positive</span> number, see below.</p>

<!-- Generate a random number -->

<input type="text" placeholder="number 1" id="number-1">
<input type="text" placeholder="number 2" id="number-2">
<input type="button" value="Generate" id="generate">
<div id="show-random-number">

</div>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

To get value from input you have to use `input.value` property. You can also use `parseInt` function to convert string value to number.

Also here's optimized version of the code.

```js
var showRandomNumberDiv = document.getElementById("show-random-number");
var number1 = document.getElementById("number-1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number-2");
var generate = document.getElementById("generate");

var newPara = document.createElement("p");
showRandomNumberDiv.appendChild(newPara);

generate.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var min = parseInt(number1.value);
  var max = parseInt(number2.value);
  
  newPara.innerText = min + Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min));
})
```

```html
<h1>Hello, and welcome to Random generator!</h1>
<h2>Not only numbers, but letters too!</h2>
<p>If you want to enter a <span style="font-style:italic; font-weight: bold;">positive</span> number, see below.</p>

<!-- Generate a random number -->

<input type="text" placeholder="number 1" id="number-1">
<input type="text" placeholder="number 2" id="number-2">
<input type="button" value="Generate" id="generate">
<div id="show-random-number">

</div>

<script src="javascript.js"></script>
```

You can multiply `Math.random()` with difference between maximum and minimum values and add the result to the minimum value to get a random number between minimum and maximum values.